# LDAP network connection lost when lid is closed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: suspend

I have a question about suspend process.
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 and LDAP client on my laptop, when I logged in via my LDAP user and close laptop's lid and when I open lid of laptop my network connection has lost, and I can not log in with my LDAP user (need to reboot laptop).
Can you help me?

Thank you in advance,
Haroyan Hayk

Comment: Hello All, Please reply my question, can anyone help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous reasons why your networking is not restarting, this is a work-around to force networking to be restarted.

Instructions are from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218043&p=13000035#post13000035

From the command line/terminal.
Create the following file and the make it executable:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Then open it in an editor:

```
 sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

or

```
gksu nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

and then paste the following in:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
pkill -f wpa_supplicant
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
```

Then save the file and exit your editor.

Comment: It is not help me. How I understand it is restart network after log in, but when I have LDAP account need to network connection before log in via my LDAP account, after resuming suspend (opening Lid of laptop), network connection icon is lost.